# Error in IE11 for matchMedia

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am running a piece of code which include following line in javascript:

```
  var mql = window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 440px)")
```

It runs fine in all browsers but in IE11 it gives error as

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'matchMedia'
```

How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: That's strange... IE has supported matchMedia for a number of years now.

Comment: I know.. but that's a bitter truth. if you go to console in ie11 and you type window.matchMedia it won't even give you a suggestion.

Comment: If I were to do it right now, no, it works just fine. I think it might be a document mode thing. Check if your page is in any legacy mode (matchMedia is not supported in IE9 and earlier).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add matchMedia.js (https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/) to your project..

In IE9 'window.matchMedia' is undefined, so that you have to add supported mediaListeners to your document. matchMedia polyfill will works for your issue..!! thanks..!!

I hope in IE11 also it will work..!!

https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/

Comment: I have same issue for IE11 and even after adding matchMedia.js it's not working.